# Substitute a string with a new line in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I want to get an output in this format:

```
# JENKIKNS start ===
<p>abc</p>
<p>def</p> 
<p>ghi</p> 
# JENKINS end ===
```

but I get this:

```
# JENKIKNS start ===
abc def ghi
# JENKINS end ===
```

My code is here:

```
ABC="abc \
def \
ghi \
"

sed -i.orig "
/java/ i\

# JENKIKNS start === \\
"$ABC"\\
# JENKINS end === \\
" sampledeploy.sh
```

Comment: You have to show the input as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at replacing \ with newline this should work

```
sed 's/\\/\\\n/g' test
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that?

```
sampledeploy.sh | sed '/# JENKIKNS start ===/ {n;s/\(\w*\)/<p>\1<\/p>/g;s/ /\n/g}'
```

**explanation**

```
sed 
'/# JENKIKNS start ===/   # search this pattern
{n                        # go to next line
;                         # next command
s/                        # substitute
\(\w*\)                   # save words into arg1 (\1)
/<p>\1<\/p>               # write \1 between tags
/g                        # on hole line
;                         # next command
s/ /\n/                   # replace ' ' with '\n'
g}'                       # on hole line
```